# JavaScript financial calculator

Tags: javascript

The following works fine however it's a static formula:

[full code](http://jsfiddle.net/5bzD3/)

```
 temp = 1+(value3/100),
 result = value4/(temp) + value4/(temp * temp) + value4/(temp * temp * temp);
```

value3 is a dynamic value coming from the following:

```
var value3 = document.getElementById('v3').value;
```

The addition (x3) in the result variable is currently static based on an input value of 3.
However if that input value changes to 2 or(any other number) how can i make the formula changing dynamically so that it would match the following?

```
result = value4/(temp) + value4/(temp * temp); (based on an input of 2)
result = value4/(temp) + value4/(temp * temp) + value4/(temp * temp * temp) + value4/(temp * temp * temp * temp); (based on an input of 4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var input = 4; // or 2, or 3, this can be anything
var result = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= input; i++)
{
    result += value4 / Math.pow(temp, i)
}
```

Comment: never come across Math.pow before, it seems to work perfectly. Thank you